# How to check php_ini variables are set?

Tags: php

I am overriding php.ini variables in my code. (ini_set("memory_limit", -1);)

How can i make sure it is set. Am using windows machine.

Is there any way i can read variable by variable with some GLOBAL array or something ?

Once i set variable, i want to read it in the next line for testing.

Answer (score 2):

Use the function [ini_get](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php).

Comment: Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php this should help explain this function a little more.

Comment: @aspect - That is the same link that is already supplied in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ini_get('memory_limit');`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after? [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php)

Answer (score 0):

Adding an live example

```
<?php

echo ini_get("memory_limit");

?>

Output:
128M (based on the value set in your php.ini).
```

Please see the link below for working example:

http://codepad.org/vm6iVDVj